# scanf not terminating

Tags: c, scanf

So, I've got the following code (C):

```
char c = getc(in);
if (c == '(')
   ...
if (c == '%')
   ...
if (isdigit(c))
{
   int n;
   ungetc(c, in);
   scanf("%i", &n);
   ...
}
```

Everything is all fine and dandy when I'm reading in input from stdin but, when reading in input from from a file, the call to `scanf` does not terminate.

I added some code around the call to see what's going on before the call to `scanf`. One such instance is

1. `c = '0'`
2. the character right after `c` is `)`

Is the buffer not flushing after `ungetc` or something? What might be happening, that it works fine when the input is `stdin` but not when its a file? (I'm not that familiar with IO in C).

edit: Should have used `fscanf`... boy is my face red.

Comment: Storing the result of `getc` in a `char` variable is always wrong. `getc` returns `int`. This is separate from your problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `getc()` will return EOF when you
   reach the end or an error occurs so
   make sure you check for that. Your `c` have to be an int, not a char to be able to distinguish EOF.
2. The same goes for scanf check its
   return value for EOF. For scanf the
   conversion might also fail,
   `scanf("%i", &n)` should return 1 if
   it successfully parsed something
   into `n` so make sure you check for
   that too.1.
3. You are also operating on `in`, as
   in `getc(in)`, suggesting you're
   reading from a particular FILE* ,
   however your scanf call still reads
   from stdin.

   Use [fscanf](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fscanf.html1.2.) instead of `scanf` there.

Comment: I've confirmed that `getc` and `ungetc` are both successful, and that `c` is definitely a digit which could be scanned back in as a number. I can't check the return value of `scanf` because it doesn't terminate. (When I interrupt the program in the debugger, it is killed in `__kernel_vsyscall__`.)

Comment: You can still write the code tho check the return value of scaf though. See the edit, you're using scanf to read from stdin when you possibly want to read from a file.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` will take input from the `stdin` file descriptor.  If redirected, then will take from the appropriate source.  `getc()` will read from any file descriptor.  You're mixing inputs from a file and stdin.

You might be more interested in [`fscanf()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf#fscanf) to read from your file.

```
char c = getc(in);
if (c == '(')
   ...
if (c == '%')
   ...
if (isdigit(c))
{
   int n;
   ungetc(c, in);
   fscanf(in, "%i", &n);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case there was an infinite loop somewhere below the scanf statement ,remove the infinite loop:

```
unsigned long x,y; 
scanf("%llu%llu",&x,&y);
while(i<=4) {   
if(list[i]>=x && list[i]<=y)        
count++;        
//i++;      
}
```